# Excel 365 - Filtering is faster when formulas reference tables in a different file

Tags: excel, filtering, excel-365

I have a file called "one.xlsb", in which there is a table called "t_formulas". That table is ~1000 rows by ~30 columns, and uses formulas to make calculations based on other tables, which contain data (these tables are called "t_data1", "t_data2", etc.).

For some reason, if these data tables are in the same file as "t_formulas", it takes ~30 seconds to apply any filter to "t_formulas".

So :

- I made a copy of "one.xlsb",
- I called the copy "two.xlsb",
- I changed all the references in "t_formulas", so that they referenced the data tables in "two.xlsb" instead of the original data tables.

  For instance, if the original formula looked like this:
  `=t_data1[@ID]=1`

  then I changed it to look like this:
  `='two.xlsb'!t_data1[@ID]=1`

Suddenly, filtering "t_formulas" took less than a second instead of ~30 seconds.

To me, that's counterintuitive: it should be faster to reference data from the same file than data in a different file.

**Does anyone know why?**

**Also, is it possible to make filtering just as fast without having to separate the data tables and the formulas table in two different files?**
It's a bit cumbersome to add 'two.xlsb' before every single reference…